# Find multiple quoted words in a string with regex

Tags: swift, regex, nsattributedstring, nsregularexpression

My app supports 5 languages. I have a string which has some double quotes in it. This string is translated into 5 languages in the localizable.strings files.

Example:

```
title_identifier = "Hi \"how\", are \"you\"";
```

I would like to bold out "how" and "you" in this string by finding the range of these words. So I am trying to fetch these quoted words out of the string and the result would be an array containing "how" and "you" or their range.

```
func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {
  do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let results = regex.matches(in: text,
                                    range: NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text))
        return results.map {
            String(text[Range($0.range, in: text)!])
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}

matches(for: "(?<=\")[^\"]*(?=\")", in: str)
```

The result is: `["how", ", are ", "you"]` rather than `["how","you"]`. I think this regex needs some addition to allow it to search for next quote once two quotes are found, so to avoid the words in between quotes.

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew the question which you suggested as duplicate is not same. The main problem is with Swift language syntax to find the correct regex with escaped quotes not in any other language.

Comment: It is the same regex. Just put into the code as a valid Swift string literal. There are a lot of valid solutions in the linked post, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1016356/3832970, https://stackoverflow.com/a/10786066/3832970.

Comment: Do you have trouble with expressing a [double quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167848/how-to-print-double-quotes-inside) or [backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170908/swift-how-to-print-character-in-a-string) in Swift code? This has been asked already, too.

Comment: Nope, My string is like that only: `var str = "They said \"Its okay\", \"well\" didn't ah ey?"`. The main problem is I have to supply a regex pattern to the swift class: `NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\b(a|b)(c|d)\\b"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];` Any regex which I try to put inside this, returns a syntactical error

Comment: If your string is `They said "Its okay", "well" didn't ah ey?` why do you think `\b(a|b)(c|d)\b` regex will help you? The simplest regex to match a string between two quotes is `"([^"]*)"`. Just use it and replace with `<b>$1</b>` if you want to put tags around the value inside two quotes.

Comment: No that was the example from Apple's site. I have used every regex from the duplicate answers by escaping double quotes. So, `"(?:\\"|.)*?" `will become `"(?:\\\"|.)*?"` for swift, by escaping the quote. But I think it messes up with the regex.

Comment: No, to use a slash, you need `"\\"`, so the ``\\`` is `"\\\\"`.  `"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*"` will look like ``let pattern = "\"(?:[^\\\\\"]|\\\\.)*\""``

Comment: So, you did not know how to escape a backslash, right?

Comment: I did know, even with escaping it is not working. That's why I made a separate question.

Comment: Now, if you still need help, taking into account what I wrote in the comments above, please check your current question and let know what is not working, update the question.

Comment: I simplified it so it can be understood by anyone one now.

Comment: So, there are two common issues: 1) matching a backlash with regex (a literal backslash needs to be matched with two backslashes, and in a Swift string literal, it needs to be coded with 4 backslashes, `let pattern = "\"(?:\\\\.|[^\"\\\\])*\""`), 2) getting all matches from a string with regex. I updated the close reasons.

Comment: I am able to make it work for a single quoted word now and not able to find a solution for multiple quoted words.

Comment: Why do you use a greedy dot (`.*`)? Use `let pattern = "(?<=\")[^\"]*(?=\")"` or - I bet it will match undesired strings - use ``let pattern = "\"([^\"]*)\""`` and grab Group 1.

Comment: Yes I see your point, it atleast will return the first occurrence only, even if there are many and not a faulty result.

Comment: A solution for extracting all matches is already linked to, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches.

Comment: Tried with a "all matches" solution. It returns the words which are not in quotes, i.e the one in between. See my updated question, you'll get the idea..

Comment: That is why I wrote *I bet it will match undesired strings*. Use `let pattern = "\"([^\"]*)\""` and grab Group 1

Comment: `matches(for: "\"([^\"]*)\"", in: "Hi \"how\", are \"you\"").map {$0.trimmingCharacters(in: ["\""])}` will do the job

Comment: It worked my man. Thanks a ton !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the use of lookarounds that do not consume text but check if their patterns match and return either *true* or *false*. See [your regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/nh46Hf/1/debugger), the `, are`  matches because the last `"` in the previous match was not consumed, the regex index remained right after `w`, so the next match could start with `"`. You need to use a *consuming* pattern here, `"([^"]*)"`.

However, your code will only return full matches. You can just trim the first and last `"`s here with `.map {$0.trimmingCharacters(in: ["\""])}`, as the regex only matches one quote at the start and end:

```
matches(for: "\"[^\"]*\"", in: str).map {$0.trimmingCharacters(in: ["\""])}
```

Here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lHuLkt/1).

Alternatively, access Group 1 value by appending `(at: 1)` after `$0.range`:

```
func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {
  do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let results = regex.matches(in: text,
                                    range: NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text))
        return results.map {
            String(text[Range($0.range(at: 1), in: text)!])
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}

let str = "Hi \"how\", are \"you\""
print(matches(for: "\"([^\"]*)\"", in: str))
// => ["how", "you"]
```